# Text is shortened during animation in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I try to build an expandable menu, The text should be limited to 2 lines, but when the text is long and the menu is expanded the text is shortened by ... during animation

```
struct MenuGroup : View {
    
    @State var show = false
    var text: String
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.show.toggle()
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Text(text)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.all, 16)
            }
            
            if show  {
                ForEach(1...3, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text("Option \(item)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            MenuGroup(text: "long text long text long text long text long text long text")
            MenuGroup(text: "long text long text long text long text long text long text")
            MenuGroup(text: "long text long text long text long text long text long text")
        } .animation(.linear(duration: 1.1))
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions is to apply `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` on  `Text`